# Swapping element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, swap

I've been trying to work this out:

Say I have an array:

```
int[] n = {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1};
```

I need to be able to sort through the array and if there is a zero with a non zero preceding it, then they should be swapped.

For example: `0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1`

will become: `0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1`

I have been trying to do it using a `for` loop and `if` statements with no luck. Any tips?

Comment: `"Any tips?"`: Yes -- please [show us what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). How else are we to guess what you may be doing wrong? How else will we know what misconceptions you may have that need to be cleared?

Comment: Great. Here come the spoon feeders. Why not first wait til we see what the OP has tried first?

Comment: They weren't exactly spoon feeding. The problem i had was not a replica of the question i asked, i just needed help on something similar, that one if statement and the the temp variable holder was a big help in me figuring out my actual problem! 
I do see why you have that particular attitude though hover.

Thanks to everyone that helped, now i just need to figure out why it's getting an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Is it too much though to ask you to show your work? I would hope not.

Comment: Not at all, i probably should of done so. I will in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < n.length ; i++)
    if (n[i] == 0 && n[i - 1] != 0) {
        int tmp = n[i - 1];
        n[i - 1] = n[i];
        n[i] = tmp;
    }
```

You were right in thinking that you would need a `for` loop with an `if` statement in its body. All we're doing here is looping through the array starting at element 1. We then check if the element we're currently on is `0` *and* the previous element is not `0`: i.e. `if (n[i] == 0 && n[i - 1] != 0)`. If this condition is true, we swap these two elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
{
    if(i > 0 && arr[i] == 0 && arr[i-1] != 0)
    {
        int temp = arr[i-1];
        arr[i-1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Why not start your for loop at i=1, since your if clause has i > 0 in the check?

Comment: True, I could do that. Yet it doesn't render the algorithm incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Without using bit twiddling, you'll need a temporary variable to swap two objects. Example:

```
int[] n = {...};
int temp = n[3]; // swaps n[3] and n[4]
n[3] = n[4];
n[4] = temp;
```

You could stick something like this inside your loop to accomplish what you described.

Comment: To the downvoter: I understand why you did this. However, I did not post a full solution, I just posted a simple example of how two variables are often swapped, with a suggestion of how to use a similar technique.

Comment: I don't see the issue with even posting the full solution as long as it coupled with some explanation. Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) (specifically the comments).

Comment: I quote [Tim Post](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post): "If you don't want a fully vetted, complete and testable answer, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask."

Comment: Yes I know - I was just speaking in general because you mentioned "I did not post a full solution" indicating that doing so would be reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Swaparray 
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        int [] arr={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
         Swaparray.displayArray(arr);
         for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
         {
         while(arr[i]%2!=0)
         {
        int tmp = arr[i - 1];
        arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
        }
        }
        Swaparray.displayArray(arr);
                     }
   static void displayArray(int[]arr)
   {
       System.out.print("Array elements are: ");
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
           System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); }
       System.out.println();
       }
}
```

o/p
Array elements are: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
Array elements are: 1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6

swapping two consecutive elements in array

Answer (score 0):

```
 int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
 int length = arr.length;
 int temp;
 for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
   {
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[length - i - 1];
    arr[length - i - 1] = temp;
   }

 for (int element:arr)
  {
    System.out.println (element);
  }
```