# Bubble Sort method swapping

Tags: java, bubble-sort

My assignment requires me to code several methods that will compare an array of first names from a .txt file.

I'm currently stuck on a BubbleSort method. Trying to get it to run.

This is my code for the BubbleSort:

```
 public static int bubbleSort(String[] array) {
    boolean swapped = false;
    int compNumber = 0;
    int length = length.array;
    while (swapped = false) {
      for (int i = 0; i < length.array-1; i++) {
        if (array[i-1] > array[i]) {
          String temp = 
          array[i-1] = array[i];
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return compNumber;
  }
```

I don't believe I'm swapping correctly because I'm not sure how to use the temp variable (hence it being blank).

Could someone take a look at this and point me in the right direction?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12653229/1980909

Comment: This code is a mess...does it even compile?

Comment: while(swapped = false) will set swapped to false before checking it, your loop will therefore never be run. You probably want `false == swapped` or `!swapped`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No sir it doesn't. I'm not done. I need to figure out how to track the number of comparisons this method will make on a lengthy String array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your algorithm is correct, but here is the standard way to swap.  If you're sorting a String array you will also need to get the numerical value (I assume the Strings contain numbers?).
Also just noticed you will get an array out of bounds exception, start at 1 if you are looking at index i-1.
One more thing, `i < length.array-1` should be `i < array.length`

And one more thing as well, the loop should continue until no swaps were made, so it should be `while (swapped == true)`, and re-set it to false in each iteration.

```
    public static void bubbleSort(String[] array) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int compNumber = 0;
    int length = length.array;
    while (swapped == true) { //note the ==
      swapped = false;
      for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        compNumber++;
        if (Integer.parseInt(array[i-1]) > Integer.parseInt(array[i])) {
          String temp = array[i-1]
          array[i-1] = array[i];
          array[i] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return compNumber; 
  }
```

Comment: What is `compNumber` used for?

Comment: Well the assignment is to create several sorting methods (Bubble Sort, Comb Sort, Cocktail Sort) and then graph the number of comparisons. I also haven't managed to figure out how I can track the number of comparisons made by this array. The code isn't done!

Comment: Just updated compNumber, that should give you the number of comparisons.